# Using python to convert string values with Calculate Field in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

In ArcGIS 10.5, I am building a model that should convert a field of coded values to another code. This seems like it should be a simple if/then statement but I am not getting it. To simplify the process, I populated the target field with the source field's values and then intend on using python to transpose the values. It should be considered a string, but the values are numerical. The field I am trying to edit is "TP_Condi"

In the "Calculate Field" code block:

```
def reclass:  
if TP_Condi = 3:    
     return 1    
elif TP_Condi = 2:     
     return 8  
elif TP_Condi = 1:    
     return 3  
else:    
     return "error"
```

---

This is the code I was seeking:

[image]

Comment: You need double == when you evaluate a condition, for example `if TP_Condi == 3`. Take a look at the examples here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0

Comment: You also need to indent everything under `reclass` by 4 spaces

Comment: I'd suggest spending a few hours on a quick online Python primer, your code has at least 4 different problems that I can see. The difference between `=` and `==` in particular is covered very early in just about every Python course I've seen.

Comment: I've spent days...it is not coming very easy to me

Comment: What is the field type of TP_Condi?

Answer (score 4):

As per comments above, you need to use double equals signs and indent the lines within your function definition.

```
def reclass(TP_Condi):  
  if TP_Condi == 3:    
     return 1    
  elif TP_Condi == 2:     
     return 8  
  elif TP_Condi == 1:    
     return 3  
  else:    
     return 0
```

Comment: @cpbride please accept this answer if it solved your issue